# HTML5 video - Force initial buffer

Tags: html, video

Quite simply, I have a `<video>` element on the page that doesn't preload, since it is fairly large, and which plays when clicked. However, obviously dependent on the user's bandwidth, it typically stutters through the playback as the video reaches the end of the buffered data stream.

Is there a way to, upon clicking the play button, delay the start of the video until a sufficient amount of it has been buffered to ensure the video won't keep pausing to wait for more data?

Comment: can you show us exactly what you have in your `<video>` tag right now. `preload="auto"` for instance should help with this

Comment: @Offbeatmammal It's just a normal video tag with no attributes, expect for id. I don't think `preload="auto"` would help because that would tell the browser to load the entire video on page load.

Comment: `preload=auto` actually asks the browser to attempt to buffer as much as it *thinks* it needs, not all the video. It isn't always accurate, depends on the browser as to what logic it follows...

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Interesting. I guess I'll just see how each browser behaves. As long as Chrome, Firefox and Safari do intelligent buffering instead of complete load it'll be fine.

Comment: Fairly intelligent ;)